# Provision vagrant Ubuntu 17.10 with ETL bonobo

Tags: pip, vagrant, python-3.6, bonobo-etl

I have the following `sh` script to provide vagrant the installation that I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Update repos
echo "Repo update time"
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update --yes --force-yes

#install python3
#no needed nowadays. Python 3.6.3 by default. Until tested the next release no update will be done.

#install pip framework for python - Python>3.4 doesn't need pip, it is bundled.
#echo "Pip time"
#sudo apt-get --yes --force-yes install --upgrade python-pip
#pip install -U pip


#install virtualenv
echo "Virtual Env time"
sudo apt-get install python3-venv #Python3 uses venv module as virtualenv


#create bonobo virtualEnv
mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments
python3 -m venv bonovo-env
source bonovo-env/bin/activate

#install bonobo framework
echo "Bonobo time"
python3.6 -m pip install --user --upgrade bonobo
```

Once, I run `vagrant provision` it seems that it is all ok because I get the following output:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/mrius/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20180228-17216-1xbxgoa.sh
    default: Repo update time
    default: 'main' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
    default: 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
    default: 'restricted' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
    default: 'multiverse' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
    default: Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
    default: Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [78.6 kB]
    default: Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB]
    default: Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main i386 Packages [211 kB]
    default: Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 Packages [215 kB]
    default: Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe i386 Packages [87.7 kB]
    default: Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe amd64 Packages [88.5 kB]
    default: Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3,412 B]
    default: Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports/universe i386 Packages [3,392 B]
    default: Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]
    default: Fetched 839 kB in 35s (23.8 kB/s)
    default: Reading package lists...
    default: W
    default: :
    default: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
    default: Virtual Env time
    default: Reading package lists...
    default: Building dependency tree...
    default: Reading state information...
    default: python3-venv is already the newest version (3.6.3-0ubuntu2).
    default: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    default: mkdir:
    default: cannot create directory 'python-virtual-environments'
    default: : File exists
    default: Bonobo time
    default: Collecting bonobo
    default:   Using cached bonobo-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting jinja2~=2.9 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting mondrian~=0.6 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached mondrian-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting python-slugify~=1.2.0 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached python_slugify-1.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting graphviz<0.9,>=0.8 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached graphviz-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting whistle~=1.0 (from bonobo)
    default:   Downloading whistle-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting psutil~=5.4 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached psutil-5.4.3.tar.gz
    default: Collecting fs~=2.0 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached fs-2.0.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting stevedore~=1.27 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached stevedore-1.28.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting packaging~=16.0 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting requests~=2.0 (from bonobo)
    default:   Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2~=2.9->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
    default: Collecting colorama~=0.3.9 (from mondrian~=0.6->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting Unidecode>=0.04.16 (from python-slugify~=1.2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached Unidecode-1.0.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting six~=1.10 (from fs~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting pytz (from fs~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached pytz-2018.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting setuptools (from fs~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached setuptools-38.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting appdirs~=1.4.3 (from fs~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from stevedore~=1.27->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached pbr-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting pyparsing (from packaging~=16.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Requirement already up-to-date: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests~=2.0->bonobo)
    default: Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached certifi-2018.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests~=2.0->bonobo)
    default:   Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    default: Building wheels for collected packages: psutil, MarkupSafe
    default:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psutil: started
    default:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psutil: finished with status 'done'
    default:   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8b/83/e9/f0feab7d059e177e6f3834f42b8a302805fd83dbb16405515a
    default:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: started
    default:   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
    default:   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/88/a7/30/e39a54a87bcbe25308fa3ca64e8ddc75d9b3e5afa21ee32d57
    default: Successfully built psutil MarkupSafe
    default: Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, jinja2, colorama, mondrian, Unidecode, python-slugify, graphviz, whistle, psutil, six, pytz, setuptools, appdirs, fs, pbr, stevedore, pyparsing, packaging, certifi, urllib3, idna, requests, bonobo
    default: Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.0 Unidecode-1.0.22 appdirs-1.4.3 bonobo-0.6.1 certifi-2018.1.18 colorama-0.3.9 fs-2.0.18 graphviz-0.8.2 idna-2.6 jinja2-2.10 mondrian-0.6.1 packaging-16.8 pbr-3.1.1 psutil-5.4.3 pyparsing-2.2.0 python-slugify-1.2.4 pytz-2018.3 requests-2.18.4 setuptools-38.5.1 six-1.11.0 stevedore-1.28.0 urllib3-1.22 whistle-1.0.0
```

but when I get into an ssh session againt the VM and run bonobo version I get:

```
bonobo: command not found
```

Why the installation is failing?

Comment: `bonobo` should be in `bonovo-env/bin/`; is it in your PATH?

Comment: @phd No, there is not bonobo :(
I have easy_install, easy_install-3.6, pip, pip3, pip3.6, python, python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not provide your vagrant file, I assume you're using a default configuration, base image `generic/ubuntu1710` with virtualbox provider (https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/boxes/ubuntu1710/versions/1.4.5/providers/virtualbox.box). I did not find any other image that looks more "official", let me know if your base is different.

I think this is more related to python packaging than bonobo but here is what happens.

- You did not install `pip` on this system. I think you want to `apt-get install python3-pip` at the same time you install `python3-venv`.
- When you run `pip install --user`, it asks explicitely to install the package in userland instead of globally in the current virtualenv. To access the installed entrypoint, you either need to add `~/.local/bin` to your system environment's `PATH`, or run directly `~/.local/bin/bonobo`. I'm not very familiar with the underlying mechanics of "userland installs".
- If you want it available in your `virtualenv`, you both need to use python/pip provided by it (`python -m ...`, try running `which python` or `which pip` to check what binary you're about to run) and avoid using `--user` flag.

On the vagrant box I installed to match your environment, the fast and dirty fix is:

- Replace `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` by `sudo apt-get install python3-venv python3-pip`
- Replace the `pip install --user` line by `pip install --upgrade bonobo`
- Run `bonobo version` (eventually).

Hope this helps.